# Visualizing a tree graph

Tags: python, graph, tree, graph-visualization

I want my python3 program to visualize a tree graph, that is generated during runtime. Every vertex has some parameters. Which parameters a vertex has depends of its depth in tree. Input data could be nested lists, which first element would specify value of the parameters or it could be root vertex and every vertex would be an object that has fields for parameters and vertexes that are above it.

Visualization should look something like this:

[image: desired output]

I tried [higra](https://higra.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tree.html):

```
import higra as hg
t = hg.Tree((7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 11, 10, 10, 11, 11))
hg.plot_partition_tree(t)
```

but it the code did not do anything when I ran it.

Every solution that is better than nothing may be helpful.

Comment: Do you have matplotlib and scipy installed?

Comment: @PabloLópez, yes. It does not raise any exceptions If I add "import matplotlib \n import scipy" in beginning of the example code.